# Converting *.eps file to *.dxf using pstoedit linux

Tags: linux, shell, svg, eps, dxf

I am doing a process of converting SVG to EPS file and EPS file to DXF file format using shell scripting. While converting EPS file to DXF file using the following command:

```
pstoedit -dt -f dxf:-polyaslines ${epsfile} ${dxffile}
```

I am facing an issue in converting the text. In the output DXF file, the text are created using polylines, So there is no text property when I open the file in DXF viewer. I need the text should be created as text in DXF file. I gone through the following link http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/pstoedit.1.html. But I didn't got the exact solution what I need. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Consider using the `convert` command from *ImageMagick* package.

Comment: It will be helpful for converting images. My case is different here

Comment: Have you tried the `-ndt` option? The docs say: `Never Draw text - fully disable the heuristics used by pstoedit to decide when to "draw" text instead of showing it as text. This may produce incorrect results, but in some cases it might nevertheless be useful. "Use at own risk".`

Comment: I need to convert text as text

Comment: I just realized you're passing `-dt`, so you're *asking* `pstoedit` to convert text into lines. Remove that option, if the symptoms persist use `-ndt` instead.

Comment: In that case I am not getting text in my output. It is blank . I need the text to be converted as text, but not drawn using polylines

Comment: Not much I can say... I you have to pass `-dt` to get any text at all, it looks like text as lines is the only result you can get.

Comment: I got text converted as ? and the warning saying that `unable to map [c2] glyph name uni0054 encoded as 1 - using the PostScript code value instead' . Any idea how to solve it @FrédéricHamidi